# apt-get update failed to fetch and /sources.list.d/ empty

Tags: sudo, upgrade, repository, error-handling

Running the `sudo apt-get update` command, I got the following error:

```
Fetched 988 kB in 16s (59,3 kB/s)                                              
W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/rebecca-getdeb/apps/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 104.28.24.125 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/rebecca-getdeb/apps/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 104.28.24.125 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I know that to solve this kind of errors, I have to modify the `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` , but, in this case, I found only those:

```
#deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 17.1 _Rebecca_ - Release amd64 20141126]/ trusty contrib main non-free
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib
deb http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/
```

`/etc/apt/source.list.d` is empty. `sudo apt-cache policy` gives:

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/apps/ubuntu/ trusty/main Translation-en
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/apps/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-ubuntuhandbook1-apps,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Apps,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/apps/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-ubuntuhandbook1-apps,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Apps,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main Translation-en
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-ubuntu-wine,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Wine Team PPA,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-ubuntu-wine,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Wine Team PPA,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://deb.playonlinux.com/ saucy/main i386 Packages
     release v=13.10,o=PlayOnLinux,a=saucy,n=saucy,l=PoL,c=main
     origin deb.playonlinux.com
 500 http://deb.playonlinux.com/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
     release v=13.10,o=PlayOnLinux,a=saucy,n=saucy,l=PoL,c=main
     origin deb.playonlinux.com
 500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty/partner Translation-en
 500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty/partner i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Canonical,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Partner archive,c=partner
     origin archive.canonical.com
 500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty/partner amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Canonical,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Partner archive,c=partner
     origin archive.canonical.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe Translation-en
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main Translation-en
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 700 http://extra.linuxmint.com/ rebecca/main i386 Packages
     release v=17.1,o=linuxmint,a=rebecca,n=rebecca,l=linuxmint,c=main
     origin extra.linuxmint.com
 700 http://extra.linuxmint.com/ rebecca/main amd64 Packages
     release v=17.1,o=linuxmint,a=rebecca,n=rebecca,l=linuxmint,c=main
     origin extra.linuxmint.com
 700 http://packages.linuxmint.com/ rebecca/import i386 Packages
     release v=17.1,o=linuxmint,a=rebecca,n=rebecca,l=linuxmint,c=import
     origin packages.linuxmint.com
 700 http://packages.linuxmint.com/ rebecca/upstream i386 Packages
     release v=17.1,o=linuxmint,a=rebecca,n=rebecca,l=linuxmint,c=upstream
     origin packages.linuxmint.com
 700 http://packages.linuxmint.com/ rebecca/main i386 Packages
     release v=17.1,o=linuxmint,a=rebecca,n=rebecca,l=linuxmint,c=main
     origin packages.linuxmint.com
 700 http://packages.linuxmint.com/ rebecca/import amd64 Packages
     release v=17.1,o=linuxmint,a=rebecca,n=rebecca,l=linuxmint,c=import
     origin packages.linuxmint.com
 700 http://packages.linuxmint.com/ rebecca/upstream amd64 Packages
     release v=17.1,o=linuxmint,a=rebecca,n=rebecca,l=linuxmint,c=upstream
     origin packages.linuxmint.com
 700 http://packages.linuxmint.com/ rebecca/main amd64 Packages
     release v=17.1,o=linuxmint,a=rebecca,n=rebecca,l=linuxmint,c=main
     origin packages.linuxmint.com
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/notepadqq-team/notepadqq/ubuntu/ trusty/main Translation-en
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/notepadqq-team/notepadqq/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-notepadqq-team-notepadqq,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Notepadqq,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/notepadqq-team/notepadqq/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-notepadqq-team-notepadqq,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Notepadqq,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu/ trusty/main Translation-en
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-noobslab-themes,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Themes Collection by NoobsLab,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-noobslab-themes,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Themes Collection by NoobsLab,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/moka/stable/ubuntu/ trusty/main Translation-en
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/moka/stable/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-moka-stable,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Moka Stable,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/moka/stable/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-moka-stable,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Moka Stable,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/release/ubuntu/ trusty/main Translation-en
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/release/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-lyx-devel-release,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=LyX PPA (release),c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/release/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-lyx-devel-release,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=LyX PPA (release),c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages
     release v=1.0,o=Google, Inc.,a=stable,n=stable,l=Google,c=main
     origin dl.google.com
 500 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
     release v=1.0,o=Google, Inc.,a=stable,n=stable,l=Google,c=main
     origin dl.google.com
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-gezakovacs,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=UNetbootin PPA,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-gezakovacs,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=UNetbootin PPA,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/rhythmbox/ubuntu/ trusty/main Translation-en
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/rhythmbox/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-fossfreedom-rhythmbox,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Rhythmbox,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/rhythmbox/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-fossfreedom-rhythmbox,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Rhythmbox,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/costales/folder-color/ubuntu/ trusty/main Translation-en
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/costales/folder-color/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-costales-folder-color,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Folder Color,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/costales/folder-color/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-costales-folder-color,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Folder Color,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/telegram/ubuntu/ trusty/main Translation-en
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/telegram/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-atareao-telegram,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Telegram,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/telegram/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-atareao-telegram,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Telegram,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://repository.spotify.com/ stable/non-free i386 Packages
     origin repository.spotify.com
 500 http://repository.spotify.com/ stable/non-free amd64 Packages
     origin repository.spotify.com
 500 http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/ Packages
     release v=14.04,o=CRAN,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=CRAN,c=
     origin cran.cnr.berkeley.edu
 700 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/ quantal/contrib i386 Packages
     origin download.virtualbox.org
 700 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/ quantal/contrib amd64 Packages
     origin download.virtualbox.org
Pinned packages:
```

Running the command `inxi -r` I get:

```
Active apt sources in file: /etc/apt/sources.list
           deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib
           deb http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/
           Active apt sources in file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list
           deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
           Active apt sources in file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atareao-telegram-trusty.list
           deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/telegram/ubuntu trusty main
           deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/telegram/ubuntu trusty main
           Active apt sources in file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/costales-folder-color-trusty.list
           deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/costales/folder-color/ubuntu trusty main
           deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/costales/folder-color/ubuntu trusty main
           Active apt sources in file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/fossfreedom-rhythmbox-trusty.list
           deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/rhythmbox/ubuntu trusty main
           deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/rhythmbox/ubuntu trusty main
           Active apt sources in file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list
           deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu rebecca-getdeb apps
           Active apt sources in file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gezakovacs-ppa-trusty.list
           deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
           deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
           Active apt sources in file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
           deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
           Active apt sources in file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lyx-devel-release-trusty.list
           deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/release/ubuntu trusty main
           deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/release/ubuntu trusty main
           Active apt sources in file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/moka-stable-trusty.list
           deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/moka/stable/ubuntu trusty main
           deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/moka/stable/ubuntu trusty main
           Active apt sources in file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/noobslab-themes-trusty.list
           deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu trusty main
           deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu trusty main
           Active apt sources in file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/notepadqq-team-notepadqq-trusty.list
           deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/notepadqq-team/notepadqq/ubuntu trusty main
           deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/notepadqq-team/notepadqq/ubuntu trusty main
           Active apt sources in file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
           deb http://packages.linuxmint.com rebecca main upstream import
           deb http://extra.linuxmint.com rebecca main
           deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe multiverse
           deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
           deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
           deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty partner
           Active apt sources in file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
           deb http://deb.playonlinux.com/ saucy main
           Active apt sources in file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ppa-trusty.list
           deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
           deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
           Active apt sources in file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntuhandbook1-apps-trusty.list
           deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/apps/ubuntu trusty main
           deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/apps/ubuntu trusty main
```

Running `cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d` and `ls -la` I get:

```
total 60
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  50 Apr  5 21:26 additional-repositories.list
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 134 Mar 21 19:59 atareao-telegram-trusty.list
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 144 Apr  4 11:18 costales-folder-color-trusty.list
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 144 Mar 27 14:10 fossfreedom-rhythmbox-trusty.list
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  57 May  1 02:23 getdeb.list
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 130 Apr  2 14:31 gezakovacs-ppa-trusty.list
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 176 Apr  5 21:26 google-chrome.list
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 136 Mar 25 23:04 lyx-devel-release-trusty.list
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 124 Mar 23 02:27 moka-stable-trusty.list
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 132 Mar 23 13:43 noobslab-themes-trusty.list
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 150 Apr  6 21:43 notepadqq-team-notepadqq-trusty.list
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 470 May  1 22:55 official-package-repositories.list
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  43 Feb 27 22:06 playonlinux.list
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 142 Mar 23 22:44 ubuntuhandbook1-apps-trusty.list
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 132 Apr 14 00:34 ubuntu-wine-ppa-trusty.list
```

Can someone suggest a solution?

Comment: What are the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`? Also, paste the output of `apt-cache policy` into your question, please. NOT AS A COMMENT..

Comment: Do you prefer I update the question or texting in the chat ? @FaheemMitha

Comment: Question updated! @FaheemMitha

Comment: Check `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` again. __NOT__ `/etc/apt/source.list.d`. There *must* be files in there.

Comment: It gives a warning message in which it says "/etc/apt/sources.list.d is a directory" and right belo "Please check that you typed the location correctly". @FaheemMitha

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what you mean. "It gives a warning message in which it says". What is "it"? Please give full context. If it is a command you typed, please give the command. And put it in the question, not a comment, please.

Comment: @FaheemMitha, sorry, it is not an error in the terminal, it is a message that comes up when the laptop tries to open the notes file.

Comment: Still not sure what you mean, What notes file? Please use a term, cd to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and do an `ls -la`. What do you see?

Comment: @FaheemMitha, sorry but I was wrong in typing the commands! I updated the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each of the urls mentioned in the error message in the question, do a search for it. Then remove it from the relevant file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.`.

For example

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
grep -R http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages
```

This will give you a name of a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. Then go into that file, and either remove the corresponding line, or edit it out using the `#` comment character. As far as I can tell, all the error messages you are seeing come from files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Comment: @Quantopic You're welcome. Is your problem fixed now?

Comment: No yet! when I do the grep command I do not get any file name. Do I have type only grep -R http://...?

Comment: @Quantopic what directory are you doing it in? Do it in `/etc/apt`. And paste the command you are using as a comment below. If it doesn't work, try putting the url in double, quotes, i.e. `grep -R "http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages"`.

Comment: I didn't realize there were other sources under sources.list.d/ directory. Once I found the offender I removed it there. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

would solve the problem

then type

```
sudo apt-get update
```

hope this solves ur problem

Answer (score 0):

It appears that my Mint 17.1 is not using /etc/apt/sources.list, but rather /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list

Please try the following command:

```
# inxi -r
```

Let me know what you get.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will update the question, @FrankRalphBob!

Answer (score -1):

Repos:     Active apt sources in file: /etc/apt/sources.list
           deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ debian main upstream import
           deb ht tp :// debian.linuxmint.com/latest testing main contrib non-free
           deb ht tp:// debian.linuxmint.com/latest/security testing/updates main contrib non-free
           deb h ttp:// debian.linuxmint.com/latest/multimedia testing main non-free
           Active apt sources in file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
           deb ht tp://packages.linuxmint.com rebecca main upstream import
           deb h tp://extra.linuxmint.com rebecca main
           deb ht tp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe multiverse
           deb ht tp:// archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
           deb ht tp:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
           deb ht tp:// archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty partner
           Active apt sources in file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
           deb ht tp:// apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux. Please read the post on formatting at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting.  Your answer is simply a list - what does it mean?